# Add time of day information to year_month_day with Howard Hinnant's date library

Tags: c++, datetime

I'm working on a specific implementation in C++. Suppose that I have a `date::year_month_day variable` from [**Howard Hinnant's date library**](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) called `X` and I want to convert it to a `std::chrono::time_point` that represents the same time as `X` but with an added offset of *A hours, B minutes and C seconds*.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant his library. I redacted my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto tp = date::sys_days{X} + hours{A} + minutes{B} + seconds{C};
```

The type of `tp` is `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, seconds>`, and represents a time point in UTC.

The only thing [**Howard Hinnant's date library**](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) adds in this example is the conversion from `date::year_month_day` to `sys_days`, which itself is just a `typedef` for `time_point<system_clock, days>`.  After that conversion, you're working entirely within the C++11/14 `<chrono>` library.